# Split function in Javascript and assigning it to variable gives different result

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I am new to javaScript and is not able to understand why split function is behaving differently just by assigning it to a variable.

For example,

```
var str = "This is text 1";
    var ani = str.split(" ");
    console.log(ani[0]);
```

The above code gives the whole word "this" , whereas for the below code

```
var str = "This is text 1";
    str.split(" ");
    console.log(str[0]);
```

It gives result as the first character of the string.

Why didn't the later code result was same to the first one?

Comment: `split` does not modify the string being split.

Comment: The first return the modified text, the second return the first character in the character array

Comment: In the second case you are not assigning `str.split(" ");` to anything. You should save ti like `let anyother = str.split(" ");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str.split(" ")` does not modify the `str` variable, it returns a new array containing the result. `str` still contains the original string, and `str[0]` is the first character of that string.

If you want to do it without assigning to a variable, apply the subscript to the function call:

```
console.log(str.split(" ")[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

String functions in javascript don't modify the string in place. So setting the result of `str.split(" ")` to a variable works, but the value of str is not changed.

Comment: split is not even just mutating, if so, it changes the type as well.

Answer (score 0):

`.split()` doesn't mutate / affect the variable it is called on, it instead returns a new value - which you have assigned to `ani`. The confusing thing for the example you have is that strings can be accessed like arrays. So `str[index]` will give the character at that position.